# How does blocks get copied from peer to peer?

Tags: blockchain, nodes, consensus

Suppose a block is accepted and validated at a node in a blockchain at a particular gas fees...... so during the process of coping the block to the other nodes of the blockchain network, can it be rejected by the miner of that particular node? ..... If so what happens to that block?

Comment: Hey everyone, I am new to this field ...... wanted to get my basics straight ........help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

If the block that arrives has been replaced by another block at the same height with higher proof of work it could be rejected. The node could still keep it around in case it becomes an uncle block.